# Two thread functions that work after each other (not concurrently)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

I have got a situation where two of my threads are working after each other.

What I want for the program to do is to draw a character (letter or number) directly after I press a key. However, what I think that happens is the following:

1. Press a key and a character appears on the screen at a certain position.
2. Press the same key to make the same character move again, but the other character appears at another, predetermined position.
3. Press the same key and the first character moves one step.
4. Press the same key "for the fourth time" and nothing happens for the first character, but I think that the second character has been redrawn in its previous position.

Here is some of the code that I am working on:

- The code for moving the character:

  ```
  static void Move(Player player)
  {       
      char c;
      while (true)
      {
          if (_kbhit)
          {
              c = _getch();
              if (c == player.charPlayer[0])
              {
                  player.posY++;
              }

              if (c == player.charPlayer[2])
              {
                  player.posY--;
              }

              if(c == 'x')
              {
                  cout << "Program is now breaking!\n";
                  break;
              }
          }
          DrawChar(player);
      }
  }
  ```
- The code for drawing the character:

  ```
  static void DrawChar(Player player)
  {
      Console::gotoxy(player.posX, player.posY);
  }
  ```
- Where the magic should have happened:

  ```
  void StartChasing()
  {
     // Create player 1 and player 2.
     Player p1('1', 'a', 'w', 'd', 's', 10, 10);
     Player p2('2', 'g', 'y', 'j', 'h', 20, 20);

     thread th1(Move, p1);
     thread th2(Move, p2);
     th1.join();
     th2.join();
  }
  ```

Thanks for any advice and please forgive any ignorant mistakes from my part since I am not familiar with the ways of stack overflow.

Comment: When you do `if (_kbhit)` it will *never* be false. The expression `_kbhit` will decay to a pointer to the function `_kbhit` and that pointer will never be a null pointer, so will always be `true`.

Comment: It seems to me that _getch is blocking and return its value to a single thread. For instance, the letter 'a' can be read by the thread of player 2. In this case, nothing is happening. A solution is to have a thread which fill a FIFO of chars. The two other threads read the input from this FIFO

Comment: Are `_getch` and `DrawChar` thread-safe?

Comment: You cannot assume anything about the order of execution of the two threads. They may execute concurrently, one after the other where it is random which one is first etc. The OS scheduler can decide to pause the thread at its will, and you cannot do anyhting against it. I am also not sure why you would need multiple threads at all.

Comment: I have realized, after receiving all of your feedbacks that I can manage with only ONE thread, hence not to worry about thread-safety. Thank you Jens for point that out. 
I will just add an extra parameter for the second character in the functions Move and DrawChar.